# ASP.NET MVC route to page with or without a route data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to develop a 2 language site and I have the requirement that if the language route value is not specified, it must go to the page with the default language.
Example:

1. [www.mysite.com/home/products?query=phone](http://www.mysite.com/home/products?query=phone)
2. [www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone](http://www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone)

Both routes should respond with the result page in english.

I have this 2 routes in the RegisterRoute():

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default2",
        url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

When i browse for the second route ([www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone](http://www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone)) I get a 404 Error.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your url [www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone](http://www.mysite.com/en/home/products?query=phone) is not working because website engine  counts en as a controller, home as action and product s as id.

If you make some research here or using google you will find a lot of solutions of your problem, but each of them has tonns of code to analyze route values, create a new url  and redirect. So  if your website is quite big with  hundreds controllers you can wrote some code. Otherwise if you have only several controllers this coud be the easiest way

```
[Route("fr/[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("en/[controller]/[action]")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Instead of fr you have to use the letters of your another language. And you don't need to use it for all controllers, it needs only for controllers where you can use an url that doesn't contain any language

And leave only one default route in your config and add MapMvcAttributeRoutes after IgnoreRoutes

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Serge. I added the 4 routes at the top of my controller as you showed. But the situation did not improve. Should I modify something in the RegisterRoute as well?

Comment: @Diego Yes, i guess you have to add MapMvcAttributeRoutes .  see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanls for your time! Anyway it's not working. I got this errror: 'The route template '/' on the action named 'Index' on the controller named 'Home' cannot begin with a forward slash.'

Comment: The error is on the line routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); and on my HomeController I got:     [Route("/")]
    [Route("it/[controller]/[action]")]
    [Route("en/[controller]/[action]")]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController